# Outlook 2013 Form Region and the Delete Key

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

So, I've finally had to deal with this annoying issue. It seems that it's a known "bug" and there doesn't seem to be a great work-around. I was wondering what seems to be the best work around for this.

A little bit of info. In my form region I have a Winform control and a WPF control. The user can't do certain key combinations on the Winform control (Ctrl-A to select all, Delete key deletes email instead of highlighted text), but everything works fine on the WPF control.

I've tried adding the Winform control to the WPF control using a WindowsFormHost, but that made it worse as it wouldn't register the backspace key after that. I tried capturing the delete event for the email, but I can't get the `.BeforeDelete` to trigger. Same for the `Explorer.BeforeItemCut` event. Currently I'm trying to capture the WndProc event to re-direct the key events, but it seems like there should be a better/easier way.

Not sure how to continue from here. Any help in direction is welcomed. Below is my how I'm trying to capture email delete event.

```
Outlook.MailItem _selEmail;

// This does get triggered
private void Explorer_SelectionChange()
{
    var actExplorer = this.Application.ActiveExplorer();
    if(this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Count > 0)
    {
        var selObject = actExplorer.Selection[1];
        if(selObject is Outlook.MailItem)
        {
            _selEmail = selObject as Outlook.MailItem;
            _selEmail.BeforeEmailDelete -=
                new Outlook.ItemEvents_10_BeforeDeleteEventHandler(Email_BeforeDelete);
            _selEmail.BeforeEmailDelete += 
                new Outlook.ItemEvents_10_BeforeDeleteEventHandler(Email_BeforeDelete);
        }
    }
}

// Haven't gotten this to trigger. The Console.Write("") is there
// only for a breakpoint;
private void Email_BeforeDelete(object sender, ref bool cancel)
{
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'd suggest breaking the chain of property and method calls and declare each property or method call on a separate line of code. Thus, you will be able to release underlying COM objects inplace. Use [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx) to release an Outlook object when you have finished using it. Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object. You can read more about that in the [Systematically Releasing Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb623945(v=office.12).aspx) article in MSDN.

Try to turn off the **Single key reading using the space bar** option in Outlook which allows you to move quickly through your messages in the Reading Pane. The space bar scrolls the current item. At the end of the item, it jumps to the next unread item in your message list.

[image]

Finally, using WPF controls on Outlook forms produce a well-known issue. Outlook has a habit of swallowing various keys and not sending them along to your code or form region. The spacebar, tab, backspace keys are among those affected when the keys are pressed in the reading pane. You can find a [similar forum thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/19b0c4be-0a8d-48cf-80f3-d0e2968e4505/wpf-form-in-vsto-outlook-addin-space-bar-advances-to-next-mail?forum=outlookdev).

Comment: Thanks for the releasing advice. I don't seem to be having problems with space bar at all and the WPF control is working perfectly (I'm able to select all text and delete). It's only the Winforms control in the region form that doesn't receive the Delete or Ctrl keys, it does get the backspace key though.